# C++: manually create a variadic template parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'd like to be able to do something like this:
Given a function:

```
void some_func(int a, int b, int c) {
   cout << a << b << c;
}

void generic_call(vector<int>& v) {
    Args... args(<make_parameter_pack_from>(v));
    some_func(args...);
}
```

`make_parameter_pack_from()` takes a vector of arguments and somehow creates a "parameter pack" from it which can then be expanded to its parameters when calling the `some_func()`.

The reason I need to do this is that I'm given the arguments in a vector and somehow I need to call a normal C++ function which takes these arguments.
I can use something like libffi to construct the function call but I was really hoping for some C++ variadic template magic which can make this happen.

Comment: There was a similar question to this a couple of days ago, but it was a `std::tuple` instead of a `std::vector`. Edit: [Found it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27798098/150634).

Comment: And if all else fails, would `some_func(v[0], v[1], v[2])` be much of a problem?

Comment: Won't work with a vector. Template magic is all resolved at compile time, when you don't yet know the size of the vector. You could do it with an array, though.